# Find and remove the space between html elments

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove a space between 2 elements in my html page.
I set `margin-left:0px;` but it does not work.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 thumb">    
                        <div class="thumbnail" href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13687120_1671928519797295_1730075489_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMwOTc1OTU2NDk2NjUzNzE2NQ%3D%3D.2" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 thumb">


                        <ul class="bullet-remover">
                            <li class="item">
                                <div class="media">

                                  <div class="media-body">
                                    <h3 class="media-heading"><strong>Luisa Martine</strong></h3>

                                            

                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

As you can see, there is a space between `image` and `ul` tag.
I have tried to remove the left margin with:

```
.bullet-remover{

    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

But it does not work?

Comment: Where can we see the space? Please make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you have some custom padding to your bullets. So one option is to cancel out the padding-left and padding-right of the ".thumb"

One more issue. please don't leave out the ".container" around your ".row". Those two are perfect & made for each other.

- container adds left and right padding which will be cancelled by the rows, so there won't be any scrollbar in the page

**Option 2:**

if you are fine with the column gutter spaces,
Then your bullet remover should be as follows

```
.bullet-remover{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style:none;
}
```

Check the snippet

```css
.thumb {
  /*padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;*/
}
.bullet-remover
{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13687120_1671928519797295_1730075489_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMwOTc1OTU2NDk2NjUzNzE2NQ%3D%3D.2" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 thumb">
      <ul class="bullet-remover">
        <li class="item">
          <div class="media">

            <div class="media-body">
              <h3 class="media-heading"><strong>Luisa Martine</strong></h3>
              

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```